# ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

bit of a long winded one here, but would really appreciate some help.

I have a `df` of stock data, and what I am trying to do is test the effectiveness of Z-scores, and am basically plotting the Z-score for each stock, and then calculating a forward return over 100 days, and plotting them against each other to determine if there's a correlation.

However, I am only interested in the extremes and only interested in the buy side, so I basically only interested in the large, negative Z-scores, let's say -3 or more negative, and their corresponding forward returns.

I also then want to get an R-square result for each stocks z score vs forward returns.

This is where I am at so far. I have my prices in a dataframe called `data` and ultimately what I want to do is enter all qualifying data in to `df`, and then plot it all. I'm trying to just get the data in to one long dataframe, as I'm not interested in the stocks name as I'm just plotting the data at the minute.

So I begin by calculating the Zscore and what I'm calling the forward return which is pretty straight forward. They both produce NaNs however, so to avoid the `df` getting gradually smaller as I loop through, I put this new data in to the `newdf` and drop the NaNs.

I then sort this `newdf` by the Zscores to return any data that's -3 or less and this is where I hit my first problem. If the stock doesn't have any data for Zscores or -3 or less it produces an error and the loop breaks.

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

This is the error I'm getting. I've tested it on `-2` and it all works fine, just so I could make sure the rest of the script worked.

I then perform linear regression to return the r-squared, and use that number as another qualifier with which to produce my final dataframe, `df`.

```
df = []

for stock in stocks:
    newdf = []
    data['zscore'] = (data[stock] - data[stock].rolling(100).mean()) / data[stock].rolling(100).std()
    data['fwd100'] = (data[stock].rolling(10).mean().shift(-105) - data[stock]) / data[stock]
    newdf.append(data[['zscore', 'fwd100']])
    newdf = pd.concat(newdf, axis=1)
    newdf.dropna(inplace=True)
    newdf.sort_values('zscore', inplace=True)
    newdf = newdf[newdf.zscore < -3]
    X = newdf['zscore'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = newdf['fwd100'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    linear_regressor = LinearRegression()
    linear_regressor.fit(X, y)
    rsq = linear_regressor.score(X, y)
    if rsq > 0.3:
        df.append(newdf[['zscore', 'fwd100']])
df = pd.concat(df, axis=0)

sns.regplot(df['zscore'],df['fwd100'])
plt.show()
```

Using `-2` as my parameter I get the following scatter graph.

[image]
So my first question is how can I stop this error occurring if a stock doesn't have any qualifying data. Secondly, is this the most efficient way for me to be doing this? I feel like I've been doing a few work arounds. And thirdly, I'm looking at 100 day Zscores and 100 day forward returns, but this is a rather arbitrary number, perhaps the optimum combination would be 75 and 125 or something, but I would have to do a bit of trial and error, is this something machine learning can help with. If so what's the best thing to google/read up on? I don't expect a huge answer I'm happy to read up on it myself.

Any help really appreciated, cheers

Here is a sample of my stock data:

```
            Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D  Stock E
Date                                                   
01/04/2019     8.17     1.11     3.22    11.58     1.20
02/04/2019     8.17     1.11     3.21    11.53     1.20
03/04/2019     8.15     1.10     3.20    11.67     1.20
04/04/2019     8.12     1.10     3.21    11.66     1.21
05/04/2019     8.11     1.10     3.19    11.57     1.19
08/04/2019     8.11     1.09     3.18    11.46     1.20
09/04/2019     8.10     1.07     3.13    11.19     1.19
10/04/2019     8.15     1.08     3.13    11.30     1.17
11/04/2019     8.15     1.08     3.11    11.20     1.18
12/04/2019     8.14     1.09     3.09    11.17     1.19
15/04/2019     8.12     1.08     3.09    11.19     1.17
16/04/2019     8.11     1.08     3.08    11.02     1.17
17/04/2019     8.15     1.08     3.04    10.94     1.17
18/04/2019     8.14     1.08     3.05    11.05     1.18
19/04/2019     8.13     1.07     3.04    10.98     1.16
```

Comment: Can you provide an sample  value of  `stocks` variable!

Comment: Hi mate, just updated, hope it helps

Comment: Can you update value of `data` as well

Comment: for your first question, is adding an if check for the series (or df) having elements before proceeding further an option? for your second question, if there **only one** variable you have to tune, I would suggest staying from machine learning and just making a script that iterates through a rational list of possible parameter values and stores the outputs.

Comment: Yeah putting an if statement in is a good idea actually, thanks mate